# How can I test if a recruitment effort was "worth it"?

Tags: survey

I am currently working on a study that involved recruiting a lot of people over a very long period of time. Participants were recruited through invitations sent by post, if they did not respond to the first letter, they would receive a second one, then a third. 
For some reason, during one wave (out of 100), they tried to knock on doors, convincing people to come join. This "door to door" attempt would only happen if the person contacted did not respond to the third letter.
How can I determine if this attempt was "worth it"(statistically)? or in other words, how can I come up with a conclusion that would either recommend this attempt to be done on a larger scale or not.
So far I have reported that the total Response rate was 12% before this "door to door" approach and became 14% after. I also measured the response rate over various subgroups to see who got affected the most. But the question remains unanswered, were these extra "2 percent" worth recruiting?

P.S- I do not have data with regards to cost, I just have data of all of those who decided to participate.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, to ensure your comparison is reliable, you would need to make sure you had controlled for other possible differences between your samples, to avoid confounding effects.

So, if the door to door approach is to be done following the third letter, you would need to have a control group (do not knock on door) and a treatment group (knock on door). Preferably, to control for socio-economic effects, in the same neighbourhood, at random. Then you could compare what happened to the recruitment rate between control and treatment groups.

Note that you might want to try this in a number of neighbourhoods (in case the first neighbourhood you choose is unusual in some way) and perhaps also to test the effect of the sampling effort (e.g. do you go back at a later time if the door knock is not answered?).

What statistical test you then use will depend on the form of your data.

If you do not have a control group, you cannot distinguish the knocking on door effect from the effect of time, word of mouth from neighbours etc. You might be able to get figures on what percentage of people who answered the door signed up immediately, but you would not know how many of them would have signed up anyway, eventually, without this approach.

Comment: People that were invited to join were Chosen at random from the City registery. If I am to compare This one wave of "door to door" recruitment, should I also choose the wave (for example) that was right before it as Control, or the one after it? or both?

Comment: The control I described in my answer would be a more satisfactory control - one carried out at the same time. Otherwise you confound your recruitment action with factors that vary over time e.g. how sunny it was, what's on TV... and other potentially more relevant things.

Comment: But if that is not a possibility for you - you can't go back in time to change the way it was done after all! - then you can still test how different this wave was, on average - just you'll have to accept that factors other than your door to door knocking could have caused some, or all, of any difference you find.

Comment: You should probably treat this as time series data. You could perhaps use all your data except for the door to door wave to construct a time series model for percentage recruitment over time - and then work out the 95% prediction intervals (NB prediction not confidence) on your time series model at the relevant point in time. If your door to door wave falls outside the 95% prediction intervals, then the door-to-door wave was very different to your other waves. If it does not fall outside, then any difference is small relative to your background variation in recruitment rate.

Comment: But would recommend that you read up on the analysis of time series, which is not something I can provide much guidance on. There may be better or more standard ways to go about this for time series data. Just keep in mind the point about confounding with other factors!